# how to check shake effect in iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone

I am using Xcode.

I have implemented the shake code. Now I want to check whether that code works or not.

How do I shake iPhone simulator??

Comment: @SpencerRuport no need for that

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In the Hardware menu, choose Shake Gesture.

Comment: That's it. Your shake handler should be called when you do so.

Comment: Can you do this programmatically?

Comment: Just to add, you can trigger this with keyboard shortcut Control-Command-Z.

Comment: Xcode 13.3 Select simulator then Go to Device menu -> Shake or from keyboard press Control+Command+Z

Answer (score 28):

The shortcut for shake is Control+Command+Z

Answer (score 9):

Aviad has the right answer, but it assumes that you are using the Shake event on the iPhone, and not a custom shake handler that works with the accelerometer.

Answer (score 5):

It is now moved -

```
Device -> Shake
```

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial on implementing shake with 3.0 seems very good.  Best I've found so far.

Yes, the shake gesture is in the simulator's hardware menu.  For other details, see the tutorial.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-1-shake-to-undoredo-nsundomanager/

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure I have seen a simulate shake command in one of the simulator's menus.