# How can I check a function that uses the accelerometer in a mobile app on my pc?

Tags: html, testing, mobile, accelerometer

I'm trying to create a mobile web application using html5. I want to check a function that is called when the user shakes his phone. How can I test this on my computer?

Comment: What sort of research and testing have you already done?

Answer (score 0):

When developing in OSX: Download xCode. It come's with a iPhone Simulator with 'Shake' support, see also [how to check shake effect in iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301615/how-to-check-shake-effect-in-iphone-simulator)